# MySQL Join returns more than expected

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is a problem that keep me 2 days of sleep.

I have 2 tables

```
views 

id | postid |   date     | count
=================================  
13 |   8    | 2016-07-16 |  38
16 |   8    | 2016-07-17 |  35
15 |   9    | 2016-07-16 |  7
17 |   9    | 2016-07-17 |  32
14 |   12   | 2016-07-16 |  17
18 |   12   | 2016-07-17 |  13


visitors 

id | postid |   date     | ip
=================================  
13 |   8    | 2016-07-16 |  127.0.0.1
17 |   8    | 2016-07-17 |  127.0.0.1
18 |   8    | 2016-07-17 |  127.0.0.1
16 |   9    | 2016-07-16 |  127.0.0.1
19 |   9    | 2016-07-17 |  127.0.0.1
14 |   12   | 2016-07-16 |  127.0.0.1
15 |   12   | 2016-07-16 |  127.0.0.1
20 |   12   | 2016-07-17 |  127.0.0.1
21 |   12   | 2016-07-17 |  127.0.0.1
```

And the following query

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT
        SUM(a.count) AS countviews, 
        COUNT(b.ip) AS countvisitors,
        a.postid
    FROM views a
    RIGHT JOIN visitors b
        ON a.postid=b.postid
        AND a.date=b.date
    WHERE 
        a.date
    BETWEEN 
        DATE_SUB('2016-07-17', INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
    AND 
        '2016-07-17' 
    GROUP BY 
        a.postid
    ORDER BY 
        countviews DESC
");
```

When i print_r the output i'll see the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [countviews] => 108
            [countvisitors] => 3
            [postid] => 8
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [countviews] => 60
            [countvisitors] => 4
            [postid] => 12
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [countviews] => 39
            [countvisitors] => 2
            [postid] => 9
        )

 )
```

Only the [countviews] result is higher then expacted. I 'm going to count and see that the countviews from postid 8 must not be '108' but '73'. The stranger thing about it is that the last count of postid 8 is '35'. '108' minus '35' = '73'. So the views tables are count double?

RIGHT JOIN, LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN gives all the same result.

Comment: You're acting like there's some mystery here. But if you omit the aggregating functions, and the GROUP BY clause, then you will know exactly which rows are returned, how many (of each), and why.

Comment: Your mysql join returns the **expected** number of rows. You just need to understand that it `SUM`S (or whatever aggregate function you use) all the rows that are displayed.

Comment: I understand, in visitors are 3 rows for postid 8 and in views 2. This means that in views a extra row appear also with the last count. How can i change the count of that row to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a join here if you want to count. The relation you made is creating multiples of the view table in case there are multiple days in your search parameters for the same postid.

You can avoid that by using subqueries:

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.count) AS countviews,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.ip) FROM visitors i WHERE b.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB("2016-07-17", INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND "2016-07-17" AND i.postid = a.postid) AS countvisitors,
    a.postid
FROM views a
WHERE 
    a.date
BETWEEN 
    DATE_SUB('2016-07-17', INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
AND 
    '2016-07-17' 
GROUP BY 
    a.postid
ORDER BY 
    countviews DESC
```

Hope I got it right. Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Had to edit it slightly. Forgot the second condition (equality of dates). Glad I could help.

Comment: When I add the i.date=a.date then the countvisitors is not given the good results. When I leave that, is working well. Thank you!

Comment: ok. I will edit that. Gathered from your query that it was needed.

Comment: ok, this was not the solution, i've got it now:

(SELECT COUNT(b.id) FROM visitors b WHERE b.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(''2016-07-17'', INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND ''2016-07-17'' AND b.postid = a.postid) AS countvisitors

changed b.date=a.date to the the date between and then it worked fine!